# Convert columns to rows Teradata

Tags: teradata

I need convert columns to rows in Teradata without TD_UNPIVOT. My table

`ID |Code_1 | Code_2 | Code_3 | Code_4|
  1 |1000   | 2000  | 3000  | 4000   |
  1 |1000   | 2000  | 3000  | NULL   |
  1 |1000   | 2000  | NULL  | NULL   |
  1 |1000   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |`

I need to convert Code_1, Code_2, Code_3, Code_4 to 2 columns: first column will have all Code_n (without NULL), second one will have Level of Code:

```
ID | Code_n | Level_of_Code
1  | 4000   | 4
1  | 3000   | 3
1  | 2000   | 2
1  | 1000   | 1
```

It means, than I should know when Code has NULL (in which level Code_1, Code_2, Code_3 or Code_4 and after that convert it to columns with numbers of max level where I have not NULL).

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: TD_UNPIVOT (http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/Table_Operators.098.21.html) what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't use td_unpivot, i don't have rights to activate it

Comment: Ugh, then you need to use `UNION`.  `SELECT ID, code_1, 1 as level_of_code from <your table> union select id,code_2 from <your table>... order by 1, 3 desc`.

Comment: thank you, and Level_of_Code I can add with case statement: `select id, code_1 as code, case when code_1 is not null then '1' end as Lefel_of_Code from <table> where code is not NULL`, yes?

Comment: It's redundant to do it in the case statement and the where clause, but it'll work, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce rows by using multiple select statements and doing a union all to concatenate them together.

```
Select id, code_1 as "code_n", 1 as "level_of_code" from your table
Union all
Select id, code_2,2
Union all
Select id, code_3,3
Union all
 Select id, code_4,4;
```